# How to find upper bound of function

Tags: algorithm

How to find the upper bound (Big O) for f(n) = 2n^3-2n^2. Want to know the C and n.

I tried below.

1. f(n)<=C*g(n)
2. 2n^3-2n^2 <= C*n^3

   My understanding of finding "C" is, consider only higher polynomial degree. So..
3. 2n^3 <= C*n^3 ---> (omitted 2n^2)
4. Thus arrived the value of C as 3.

But the answer given in my book is C = 2.

question 1: Please clarify how C will be 2.

question 2: how to find the value of n.

Comment: Factor out `2n^2` to obtain `f(n) = 2n^2*(n-1)`. Surely `2n^2*(n-1)<=2n^2*n=2n^3` (since `n - 1 < n`). So for `C := 2` and `g(n) := n^3` the equation `|f(n)| <= C*g(n)` which is required by the definition of Big O is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality you have to prove is:

```
2n^3-2n^2 <= C*n^3 for all n >= n0.
```

Actually, any C >= 2 works. n0 in this case can be taken to anything >= 0.

Comment: can you please give me the steps to get C >= 2? I hope it is not trial and error method of finding.

Comment: It kind of is trial and error. In your example however it is trivial. A slightly more interesting case would be the function: `2n^3+2n^2`. It it still in O(n^3), But C=2 does not work here. What would you take instead?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

To find a constant `C` you have to analyze the terms of smaller order. In this case this is easy because `-2n² ≤ 0`. Therefore, the terms of lower order can be disregarded. In other words, we just observe that

```
  2n³ - 2n² ≤ 2n³ - 0 = 2n³.
```

Then

```
  2n³ ≤ Cn³ ⟺ 2 ≤ C.
```

and it suffices to take `C = 2`.

The problem would have been more interesting in the case `2n³ + 2n²` because here we cannot disregard the quadratic part. In that case, we can simply observe that `n² ≤ n³` and so

```
  2n³ + 2n² ≤ 2n³ + 2n³ = 4n³
```

and could take `C=4`. Following this line of reasoning, one should be able to cope with most similar situations.

Answer (score -1):

Given

```
        f(n) = 2n^3-2n^2
        g(n) = n^3
```

we want to find `c` such that `f(n) <= c(g(n))`, i.e.,

```
        2n^3-2n^2 <= c(n^3)
```

Let's try `c=3`. Then

```
        2n^3-2n^2 <= 3n^3
        -2n^2 <= 3n^3-2n^3
        -2n^2 <= n^3
        -2 <= 1
```

Therefore, we can take `n0=1` and `c=3`.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**